# saving temporary form on MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently working on a database project using MS Access that allows user to submit their applications via forms and these applications get saved on a masterlist table. I am wondering if MS Access has the ability to support features which allows a user to save a form which they have filled, but not officially submitting it yet, and afterwards at their own discretion they can re-enter to submit their forms, which then only gets captured in the masterlist table. Any suggestions to architect this feature are welcome, or any limitations in doing so

Comment: No, there's no built in ability to do so. You'll need to code it yourself. You already know what you're saving as your final input; just mirror that to store an intermediate set of values as your *temporary form* data. When the user finalizes, you move it from there to your actual storage location and delete it from the *temporary form* data.

Answer (score 1):

Second suggestion Calls for a few preparations, but makes submitting a very simple task:

1. Assuming table name is `masterlist`, add to the table a field
   `Submitted`, Boolean value (*Yes/No* Value), Default Value = False.
    Submitting an application will be done by setting this Field to *`True`*.
2. Change `masterlist` table name to `tbl_masterlist`, and create a query:
   `SELECT * FROM tbl_masterlist Submitted = TRUE`. Name this query `masterlist`.
   **Now `masterlist` has only submitted applications**.
3. In design view, Change the Form's RecordSource Property to `tbl_masterlist`. You can filter out undesired applications from the Form, if you wish, using the From's `Filter` and `FilterOn` property
4. add a checkBox field to `applications` Form, and in the properties window s set it's `Name` and `ControlSource` Properties to `Submited`, and it's `Visible` property to ***`False`***.
5. Finally, add to `applications` Form a `Submit` Button, and in it's `OnClick` event sub add this code: `Me.Submited = True`.

Comment: This. A flag to distinguish Temporary/Submitted records is a much better solution than a separate table.